# integrability of ker $\omega$ in symplectic case

Tags: geometry, manifolds, symplectic-geometry

How can we prove that if $(M,\omega)$, is pre-symplectic and d$\omega=0$  then ker$\omega$ is integrable?.

Comment: Since $\omega$ is a nondegnerate $2$-form, what do you mean by $\ker\omega$?

Comment: Ah ... I see from your post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432417/a-question-about-pre-symplectic-manifold that we're having a problem with definitions. If you assume $\omega$ has constant rank, then this should follow from the general version of Darboux's Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem

Comment: Why rank should be constant?

Comment: If it isn't constant, you can't choose local coordinates $(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n)$ with $\omega =\sum\limits_{j=1}^p dx_j\wedge dy_j$.

Comment: ohhhh, yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more invariant language, you can see this as follows: let $X,Y$ be vector fields contained in $\ker\omega$. Then $$
\mathcal{L}_X\,\omega = d(i_X\omega)+i_X(d\omega) = 0
$$
using Cartan's Magic Formula. Then, using the identity (see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative))
$$ i_{[X,Y]}\omega = [\mathcal{L}_X,i_Y]\,\omega$$
we see that $i_{[X,Y]}\omega = 0$. It follows that $\ker \omega$ is involutive, and hence by Frobenius' Theorem, integrable. Application of Frobenius' Theorem requires that $\ker\omega$ defines a subbundle of $TM$, which is equivalent to $\omega$ having constant rank.